# Display information from MySQL Database on webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

```
<h1>Matches</h1>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","esports");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM NA");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['team1'] . " vs. " . $row['team2'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm trying to use this to get information from my MySQL Database and then display it onto a webpage using an HTML Table. I'm kind of new to this, so how would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: inside your while loop, add print_r($row); and see if it tells you anything that helps. Also you could try adding or die(mysql_error) to your query and see if it gives you anything. I'm sure mysqli has a similar function to mysql_error.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any problem with your query, so if you want to just format it as a table, you could do

```
echo "<table border=1>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
  {
  echo '<tr><td>';
  echo $row['team1'];
  echo '</td><td>';
  echo $row['team2'];
  echo '</td></tr>';
  }
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: I seem to be getting this now.

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/html/get/index.php on line 16

Comment: My mistake, there should be two `)`s after the $result instead of just 1

Answer (score 0):

To connect to MySQL database you need to use mysql_connect and select the database with mysql_select_db and finally do a mysql_fetch_array

```
<?php

$con    =mysql_connect("localhost","root","","esports");
mysql_select_db('your data base');

$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM NA");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r( $row);
   echo '</pre>';
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```